# Añadir componentes a Grid de forma ordenada en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Quisiera saber cómo puedo agregar componentes a un Grid en WPF en tiempo de ejecución de manera que me aparezcan uno detrás de otro. Hasta ahora lo tengo así:
[image: Menú actual]

Implementado con el siguiente código:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="892" Margin="106,0,0,0">
   <Label Content="Parametrización" Margin="405,63,405,0" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FFB9B9B9"/>
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackParametros" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59" Margin="0,3,0,0">
      <Image Height="32" Source="support-32.png"/>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Parámetros" FontSize="10" Margin="0,0,-3,0" TextAlignment="Center"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackInformes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" Margin="64,3,0,0">
      <Image Height="32" Source="dossier-32.png"/>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="10" Text="Definición de Informes" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
   </StackPanel>
   ...
   ...
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackColumnas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Margin="810,3,0,0">
      <Image Height="32" Source="search-32.png" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Columnas" FontSize="10" Height="28" TextAlignment="Center"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Pero esos botones están establecidos de forma estática.
El caso es que no siempre tienen que aparecer todos y la forma más sencilla de hacerlo es, el que no se tenga que ver se marca como no visible, pero en ese caso se quedarían los huecos entre botón y botón y yo lo que quiero es que aparezcan sólo los necesarios y en orden.

Conclusión, lo que quiero es saber cómo puedo hacer que, cuando se vaya a cargar la ventana, se vayan añadiendo los elementos que correspondan y uno al lado del otro.

Un saludo y garcias!

PD: Estoy usando C# con WPF, los elementos del cuadro rojo son StackPanels y están dentro de un grid del tamaño más o menos del que tiene el rectangulo pintado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado.
Para ir añadiendo los elementos desde el principio lo que hay que hacer es añadir "Columnas" al Grid por cada elemento que vayas a añadir, indicarle que su tamaño será automático y después añadir el elemento indicándole su columna. 
En mi caso, los elementos que quiero introducir me los indica la información de un DataRow, lo he conseguido de la siguiente forma:

```
int pos = 0;
ControlMenu cm;
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    gridAux.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

    cm = new ControlMenu();
    cm.text.Text= item["Texto"].ToString();
    cm.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    cm.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    cm.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, pos);

    gridAux.Children.Add(cm);

    pos++;
}
```

Comment: Estimado, solo necesitas colocar un StackPanel  con Orientation en 'Horizontal' dentro del Grid y añadir los objetos con Visibility en 'Collapsed' o 'Visible', el stackPanel ordenará todo automáticamente, es más, lo que esté en collapsed ni siquiera necesitas agregarlo, el StackPanel lo ajusta todo solito :)

Answer (score 1):

A la propiedad `Visibility` de los controles asignale `Visibility.Collapse` que oculta en elemento y desocupa el espacio porlo que no te quedará el espacio vacío.

O puedes agregar los elementos al `Grid` utilizando la propiedad [`Children.Add(Control)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ejemplo:

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock{ Text = "Hola Mundo" };
GridName.Children.Add(t);
```

Comment: Cuando añado varios elementos con el Children.Add se ponen uno encima de otro..